# Get week start/end dates and week number for weeks starting on Thursday

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have this existing project which is a weekly report. One of its parameters are the week range. It works fine but they need to rebump the report, instead of starting the week in the first day of the year they need to start the week on the first thursday and end on a wed. I have this query

```
SELECT   MIN([DATE]) as StartWeek
            ,MAX([DATE]) as EndWeek
            ,DATENAME(WEEK,Convert(datetime,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATE,[DATE]),101))) as [WEEK]

    FROM [somedb]
    WHERE DATENAME(Year,Convert(datetime,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATE,[DATE]),101))) = 2018
    GROUP BY DATENAME(WEEK,Convert(datetime,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATE,[DATE]),101)))
```

The output of this query is

```
Start Week    End Week    WEEK
2018-01-01    2018-01-07  1
```

The expected output should be

```
Start Week                                         End Week    Week
2018-1-4(since its the first thursday of the week) 2018-1-10    1
```

Yes I can `DATEADD` but the week number will still acknowledge 2018-1-8 as `WEEK 2`

Comment: Do you just want the dates for the first week?

Comment: @SalmanA all through out the year

Comment: See revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @WeekDay Varchar(500),
        @Add     Int,
        @DATE    Date;

        SET @DATE = '2018-01-01';

        SELECT @WeekDay = DATENAME(DW,@DATE);

        SELECT @Add = CASE
                      WHEN  @WeekDay    =   'Thursday'  THEN 
                      0
                      WHEN  @WeekDay    =   'Friday'    THEN 
                      6
                      WHEN  @WeekDay    =   'Saturday'  THEN 
                      5
                      WHEN  @WeekDay    =   'Sunday'    THEN 
                      4
                      WHEN  @WeekDay    =   'Monday'    THEN 
                      3
                      WHEN  @WeekDay    =   'Tuesday'   THEN 
                      2
                      WHEN  @WeekDay    =   'Wednesday' THEN 
                      1
                  END

SELECT  DATEADD(DD,@Add, CONVERT(DATE,@DATE))   AS WeekStart,
        DATEADD(DD,@Add+6, CONVERT(DATE,@DATE)) AS WeekEnd,
        1                                       AS Week
```

Comment: This doesn't return what week number of the year.

Answer (score 0):

We can start by setting the first day of the week to Thursday, using the [SET DATEFIRST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement. This means, further calculations will take a Thu to Wed week instead of the usual.

You could then restrict your data to start from the first Thursday of the year and finally, just subtract 1 from `WEEK` to get the desired output.

```
  set datefirst 4 --Set Thursday as first day of the week

  SELECT MIN(dt) as StartWeek, MAX(dt) as EndWeek, DATENAME(WEEK,dt)-1 as [WEEK]
  FROM #tbl
  WHERE YEAR(dt) = 2018
  AND dt >= (select min(dt) from #tbl where datename(WEEKDAY,dt) = 'Thursday')
  GROUP BY DATENAME(WEEk,dt)
```

If you remove the `AND` condition from the filter, your first row will be week 0 containing the three days in the year before the first Thursday. Even then, your week starting 4th Jan 2018 still has the number 1.

UPDATE: The below should be able to adjust for weeks split across 2 years.

```
set datefirst 4 --Set Thursday as first day of the week

select *, case when datepart(week,d1) > datepart(week,d2) then datepart(week,d1) else datepart(week,d2)-1 end from
(
select d1, max(d2) d2 from
(select t1.dt d1, t2.dt d2
from #tbl t1
inner join #tbl t2 on datediff(day,t1.dt,t2.dt) between 1 and 6
and t1.dt < t2.dt
and datename(weekday, t1.dt) = 'Thursday') s 
group by d1) t
```

- Once again, set start of week to Thursday.
- Next, get all Thursdays in your data set and find the corresponding end of week.
- Finally, add a check for whether the week is in the same year - if it is not, take the week number for the earlier year's start date. This will give you the continuity that you expect.

I've set up a test here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=75582819ff0defb7366592f4a89e9604

Comment: Jan 1 2018 - Jan 3 2018 should be counted as last week of the previous year since the last thursday is Dec 28 2017

Comment: So you want it to have value 52, and the week from 4th Jan as value 1 again?

Comment: yeah. That should be the right answer if you count the weeks.